# Get the cellular network information of the mobile number before calling

Tags: networking, mobile, cellular-network

We have an office network and hundreds of calls are being made daily on land lines and mobiles with different cellular networks.

My idea is that we have a system that will check intelligently that on which cellular network we are going to call. The advantage of identifying the network is that, (assuming every type of cellular network SIM is installed in our system) system will call that number from the same network on which we are calling.

By doing this we can decrease the charges, as call on the same network has less fares then calling on another network.

So I want to ask, is there a way through which we can identify the network of called number?

Comment: Is there a reason why this is a c# and android question?

Comment: Yes, as It will be an android application and also a desktop for landline users.

Comment: As this is a programming Q&A website, when you tag c# and android, we expect to see code for those languages/platforms.  Future use of information that you get here is not applicable.

Comment: dear i was asking about the solution, like one told about api in android, anyway would you please tell me solution that how to achieve this?

Comment: Please add the solution that you finally followed if any you could find ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) API you can get the network information of incoming call, but for outgoing call you can no do same.

Comment: Actually we can do it by using a static check on code as most of the people use converted numbers.